# UpdateView and DeleteView lead to error 405 when submit is clicked

Tags: python, django

CreateView loads a form and when submit is clicked it redirects to the detail page of the new object; UpdateView correctly loads the form template already filled with the information about the current object but when submit is clicked to save the updates leads to a 405 blank page and the object is not updated; The same happens with DeleteView: 405 error and the object isn't deleted, the only difference is that DeleteView loads a different template form.

It seems a common problem, I found different solutions on similar questions here but none is working for me. I'm stuck from a couple of days so any hint is really appreciated. Since I'm learning I would like to have some explanation about why this occours rather than some code I have to copy/paste. Thanks all.

```py
# urls.py
app_name = 'articles'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticleListView.as_view(), name='article-list'),
    path('create/', ArticleCreateView.as_view(), name='article-create'),
    path('<int:id>/update', ArticleUpdateView.as_view(), name='article-update'),
    path('<int:id>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
    path('<int:id>/delete', ArticleDeleteView.as_view(), name='article-delete')
```

```py
#models.py
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("articles:article-detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

```py
# views.py
class ArticleListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'templates/blog/article_list.html'
    queryset = Article.objects.all()


class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'blog/article_detail.html'

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Article, id=id_)


class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'blog/article_create.html'
    form_class = ArticleForm
    queryset = Article.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)


class ArticleUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'blog/article_create.html'
    form_class = ArticleForm
    queryset = Article.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Article, id=id_)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)


class ArticleDeleteView(DeleteView):
    template_name = 'blog/article_delete.html'

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Article, id=id_)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('articles:article-list')
```

```html
/* template form for DeleteView, can post template form for UpdateView if needed*/
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Want to delete "{{object.title}}"?</h1>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Yes" /><a href="../">Cancel</a> </p>
</form>
```

I get a 405 page not working, django doesn't specify any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update` and `delete` URLs don't have a trailing slash. Therefore `action="."` is causing the form to be submitted to the `'article-detail'` URL.

You could fix this by adding the trailing slash to the URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticleListView.as_view(), name='article-list'),
    path('create/', ArticleCreateView.as_view(), name='article-create'),
    path('<int:id>/update/', ArticleUpdateView.as_view(), name='article-update'),
    path('<int:id>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
    path('<int:id>/delete/', ArticleDeleteView.as_view(), name='article-delete')
]
```

Or you could use the URL tag to ensure that the forms action is correct.

```
/* template form for DeleteView, can post template form for UpdateView if needed*/
<form action="{% url 'articles:article-delete' article.pk %}" method="POST">
...
    <p><input type="submit" value="Yes" /><a href="{% url 'articles:article-detail' article.pk %}">Cancel</a> </p>
```

You could also use `action=""`, but reversing the URL is probably more robust.

Answer (score 1):

You have created separate urls and views for `GET` and `DELETE` actions.

So you need change the `action` parameter in your HTML form so that an HTTP request is made to the `article-delete` url using the `url` [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Also, you seem to be building an app very similar to a popular Django open source project called [bootcamp](https://github.com/vitorfs/bootcamp). This project follows all the best-practices. You can read its source to learn how to write clean, idiomatic Django code.